# -bash: ../binutils-2.38/configure: Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, gcc, operating-system

I follow Bare Bones Tutorial on OSDev wiki then I type this `../binutils-2.38/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror`
then It show me this
`-bash: ../binutils-2.38/configure: Permission denied`

edit: I use ubuntu wsl, I download binutils-2.38 and gcc-11.4.0

Comment: Verify, that `configure` is a plain file, and that you have execute permissions: Either by `ls -ld ../binutils-2.38/configure` or a `stat ../binutils-2.38/configure`.

Comment: BTW, this is not a programming quesition, but could be asked at i.e. [su].